# Django template - Context Variable Lookup TypeError

Tags: django, templates, typeerror

I am learning Django,using the resource Django Book: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html

However, when I follow the example about "Context Variable Lookup",I got Error "TypeError: expected string or buffer".

The example code is (copied form the book):

```html
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(1993, 5, 2)
>>> d.year
1993
>>> d.month
5
>>> d.day
2
>>> t = Template('The month is {{ date.month }} and the year is {{ date.year }}.')
>>> c = Context({'date': d})
>>> t.render(c)
u'The month is 5 and the year is 1993.'
```

I think I have to convert d.day and d.month to string.
Any help to clarify this point, thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you are running?

Comment: Hm, in my case it works fine. Which version of django are you using?

Comment: I am using django 1.8

Comment: Semi-related, you shouldn't be using that tutorial. Like they said in the table of contents it was written for Django a good 3/4 years ago. Their code is outdated and very likely to give you errors.